# Regex for tollfree numbers in java

Tags: java, regex

I have this regex to test for telephone # that should be a toll free.

```
public static final Pattern patternTollFree = Pattern.compile("^((877)|(800)|(866)|(888))");
```

So I only want to get those # where the user may have left the 1 off of the front of the string, but I have tried several things and I can't get java to match.

```
public String changeRingTo( String changedRinger )
{
    if ( null == changedRinger || changedRinger.length() != 10)
        return changedRinger;
    if ( patternTollFree.matcher(changedRinger).region(0, 2).matches() )
        changedRinger = '1' + changedRinger;
    return changedRinger;
}
```

I can't get this 2nd test case below to succeed.  What am I doing wrong?

```
assertEquals( "Regex not working", "8189091000", of.changeRingTo("8189091000"));
assertEquals( "Regex not working", "18769091000", of.changeRingTo("8769091000"));
```

Comment: Be aware that this is quite country specific.

Comment: That is fine, because this is for southeastern US only.

Comment: But be aware that phone numbers can be formated in several different ways (like +1 (877) 1234567 or 001877123 or whitespaces and so on)

Comment: The format will only be in the way it is specified above.  No spaces, dashes, etc.  When the code gets to the area I am testing it has been scrubbed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second test case fails because it starts with `876` which is not a valid toll free prefix. Additionally, as indicated in the other answer, you should change `region(0, 2)` to `region(0, 3)` although that entire line could be significantly simplified.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that.  That was the whole problem.  How could it be simplified?  8((66)|(77))

Comment: @arinte: Change it to `if (changedRinger.matches("^(877|800|866|888)\\d+$"))` and get rid of the `patternTollFree` variable entirely.

Comment: If you precompile your pattern it is supposed to have better performance.

Comment: @arinte: Is that kind of micro-performance difference significant in your application? If not, I would opt for readability over performance.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `region` is exclusive, not inclusive.  Right now you are only allowing it to check the first two characters of the input.  You need to change it to

`if ( patternTollFree.matcher(changedRinger).region(0, 3).matches() )`

See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#region%28int,%20int%29

Note that it is redundant to use `^` in your regex and also specify the region on your matcher.